# Copy HTML form in email PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to copy my HTML form in email body. Below is code where the form is already in php file but I want if the user submits html form file then all the form data between   that is not hidden is copied (as disabled elements) in the body of the email. Also if there is any file attachment field, it should be attached to the email.

```
<?php
// multiple recipients
$to  = 'demo@localhost.com' . ', '; // note the comma
$to .= 'demo@localhost.com';

// subject
$subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';

// message
$message = '
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />


<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body style="padding:3px; margin:0px;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="440">

    <tr><td style="height:10px"></td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="text-align:justify; line-height:15px;" class="body">

      <form name="frm" method="POST" action="careersuccess.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
          <tr>
            <td width="23%" class="body"> Name</td>
            <td width="3%" class="body">:</td>
            <td width="74%"><input type="text" name="strname" class="textfield"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td style="height:3px"></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="23%" class="body"> Address</td>
            <td width="3%" class="body">:</td>
            <td width="74%"><textarea cols="16" name="straddress"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td style="height:3px"></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="23%" class="body"> City</td>
            <td width="3%" class="body">:</td>
            <td width="74%"><input type="text" name="strcity" class="textfield"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td style="height:3px"></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="23%" class="body"> State</td>
            <td width="3%" class="body">:</td>
            <td width="74%"><input type="text" name="strstate" class="textfield"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td style="height:3px"></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="23%" class="body"> Contact No</td>
            <td width="3%" class="body">:</td>
            <td width="74%"><input type="text" name="strno" class="textfield"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td style="height:3px"></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="23%" class="body"> Email</td>
            <td width="3%" class="body">:</td>
            <td width="74%"><input type="text" name="stremail" class="textfield"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td style="height:3px"></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="23%" class="body"> Comments</td>
            <td width="3%" class="body">:</td>
            <td width="74%"><textarea cols="16" name="strcomments"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td style="height:3px"></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="23%" class="body"> Resume</td>
            <td width="3%" class="body">:</td>
            <td width="74%"><input type="file" name="strresume"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td style="height:10px"></td></tr>
        <tr>

        </tr>

      </table>   
     </form>

</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center"> </td>
  </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: I don't think all email clients will accept forms in your email moreover to send post data.

Comment: So am I getting this right? You wish to add a formular in the body of an email? Talking about innovation here ..

Comment: I want to copy selected form data in the body of email. Why is there an issue ?

Comment: Most email programs/websites have very limited html capabilities. I don't believe input boxes are supported by any of them. For example here is Microsoft Outlook's list of supported html tags. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: You will notice <input> is not listed as a supported type. It does look like they support <textarea> so you could possibly use textareas for everything and just make them one row so they look like a normal input text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume the form is submitted from a website, and that you're not trying to create a submittable form in an email. To copy the data submitted in the form, $_POST[""]; would surely be the best way to obtain the data. Obviously the data wouldn't be manipulatable once the email has arrived in the recipient's inbox but, as I say, I'm assuming you're not trying to create a form which can be submitted from an email.

Your form on the website was fine:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />


<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body style="padding:3px; margin:0px;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="440">

<tr><td style="height:10px"></td></tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2" style="text-align:justify; line-height:15px;" class="body">

  <form name="frm" method="POST" action="careersuccess.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td width="23%" class="body"> Name</td>
        <td width="3%" class="body">:</td>
        <td width="74%"><input type="text" name="strname" class="textfield"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td style="height:3px"></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="23%" class="body"> Address</td>
        <td width="3%" class="body">:</td>
        <td width="74%"><textarea cols="16" name="straddress"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td style="height:3px"></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="23%" class="body"> City</td>
        <td width="3%" class="body">:</td>
        <td width="74%"><input type="text" name="strcity" class="textfield"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td style="height:3px"></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="23%" class="body"> State</td>
        <td width="3%" class="body">:</td>
        <td width="74%"><input type="text" name="strstate" class="textfield"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td style="height:3px"></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="23%" class="body"> Contact No</td>
        <td width="3%" class="body">:</td>
        <td width="74%"><input type="text" name="strno" class="textfield"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td style="height:3px"></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="23%" class="body"> Email</td>
        <td width="3%" class="body">:</td>
        <td width="74%"><input type="text" name="stremail" class="textfield"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td style="height:3px"></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="23%" class="body"> Comments</td>
        <td width="3%" class="body">:</td>
        <td width="74%"><textarea cols="16" name="strcomments"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td style="height:3px"></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="23%" class="body"> Resume</td>
        <td width="3%" class="body">:</td>
        <td width="74%"><input type="file" name="strresume"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td style="height:10px"></td></tr>
    <tr>

    </tr>

  </table>   
 </form>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2" align="center"> </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Your file careersuccess.php would then need to include something like:

```
<?php
// multiple recipients
$to  = 'demo@localhost.com' . ', '; // note the comma
$to .= 'demo@localhost.com';

// subject
$subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';

$strName = $_POST["strname"]; //assigns strname from form to PHP variable
$strAddress = $_POST["straddress"];
$strCity = $_POST["strcity"];
$strState = $_POST["strstate"];
$strNumber = $_POST["strnumber"];
$strEmail = $_POST["stremail"];
$strComments = $_POST["strcomments"];
$strResume = $_POST["strresume"];
$lineBreak = "<br />\n\"; //adds carriage return to break up your message

$message = "Name: ".$strName.$lineBreak."Address: ".$strAddress.$lineBreak."City: ".$strCity.$lineBreak."State: ".$strState.$lineBreak...for the rest of your variables;

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

That will result in the submitted values of the form being copied in to the email in the $message variable for the mail() function.